# The method is ambiguous for the type Error

Tags: java, overloading, ambiguous

I am trying to understand how Overloading in JAVA works and trying to get grasp of various overloading rules that are applied in case of widening, autoboxing and varargs in JAVA. I am not able to understand what is happening in the following scenario:

```
 package package1;

 public class JustAClass {
     public static void add(int a, long b) {
         System.out.println("all primitives");
     }

   //public static void add(Integer a, long b) {
   //     System.out.println("Wraper int, primitive long");
   //}

     public static void add(int a, Long b) {
         System.out.println("Primitive int, Wrapper long");
     }

     public static void add(Integer a, Long b){
         System.out.println("All wrapper");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 10;
        Integer b = 10;
        long c = 9;
        Long d = 9l;

        add(a,c);
        add(a,d);
        add(b,c);
        add(b,d);
 }

}
```

At this point, I get a compilation error at the third invocation of the `add` method saying `The method  is ambiguous for the type Error` .
Why is this so? What are the rules for determining which invocation of method will work? What is exactly happening in the following case? 
I feel that `fourth` overloaded add method should work. Please help me understand the concept behind this.

Comment: The rules are in the Java Language Specifications, and they are extremely long and complex. Remembering them is basically impossible, and this is why you should never, ever write code like the above, because you can be almost certain to introduce bugs. I respect your desire to understand, but to do that, you should read the JLS: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: @JBNizet: I think the question is totally legit. You can learn the specification by breaking it and understand why it breaks, then never do it again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 3 stages to method overloading resolution. The first stage doesn't do auto-boxing/unboxing, which means methods that require boxing/unboxing of the passed parameters in order to match one of the overloaded versions of `add` will only be considered if no match was found that doesn't require boxing/unboxing. That's why 3 of your calls, which have a single exact match, work. Regarding `add(b,c);`, see below why it's ambiguous.

```
   add(a,c); // exact match to add(int a, long b)
   add(a,d); // exact match to add(int a, Long b)
   add(b,c); // there is no exact match, so at least one of the passed parameters must
             // be boxed or unboxed. However, by unboxing b to int or boxing 
             // c to Long, each of the three add methods can match, and the 
             // compiler doesn't know which one to prefer
   add(b,d); // exact match to add(Integer a, Long b)
```

Comment: @NeerajDorle I didn't mean just one, I meant at least one. Perhaps I should re-phrase that.