# Why doesn't the lambda example in hankcs/AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie work?

Tags: java, lambda, aho-corasick

I'm just copying the example from this [github project page](https://github.com/hankcs/AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie) without any change and it's giving me a compile error

To reproduce, add this dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hankcs</groupId>
  <artifactId>aho-corasick-double-array-trie</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then try to run this:

```
    // Collect test data set
    TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    String[] keyArray = new String[]
            {
                    "hers",
                    "his",
                    "she",
                    "he"
            };
    for (String key : keyArray)
    {
        map.put(key, key);
    }
    // Build an AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie
    AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie<String> acdat = new AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie<String>();
    acdat.build(map);
    // Test it
    final String text = "uhers";
    acdat.parseText(text, (begin, end, value) -> {
        System.out.printf("[%d:%d]=%s\n", begin, end, value);
    });
```

The compile error is

```
The method parseText(CharSequence, AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie.IHit<String>) is ambiguous for the type AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie<String>
```

Please let me know if you need anything to clarify. You should be able to reproduce this with what I have provided here though.

Also, it's been suggested this may be a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34556239/the-method-is-ambiguous-for-the-type-error) when I posted this previously, but I do not think that's the case as that question is not related to lambda functions. If I'm wrong, please help me understand how that question's answer can resolve what I'm experiencing

Comment: Have you tried running the code without using a lambda? If you get the same error, then this is still a duplicate question and the other answers are valid. The error does not appear to have anything to do with the fact that you're using lambda.

Comment: Maybe the example is an old example and since it has been written another method has been added to the library, check how many methods the library contain, that are called "parseText" an verify which are the differences in the signatures

Comment: @Zephyr navy1978 There are 4 methods called parseText. Because I am new to lambda functions, I don't know how to tell which of those 4 functions this lambda syntax is trying to invoke. Or if someone can explain how to invoke any of the 4 methods using lambda, I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie` has two methods called `parseText`, one with `IHit`, another with `IHitCancellable` as parameter. Both interfaces declare a method `boolean hit(int begin, int end, V value)`, so by using a lambda, the compiler doesn't know what method you intend to call.

I haven't found a quick solution by googling but what you can do is declare your own class extending `AhoCorasickDoubleArrayTrie` with an own method that is calling the intended method in the super class that has the interface you want to use, e.g.

```
void myParseText(String text, IHit<V> hit) {
    super.parseText(text, hit);
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you. You helped me understand something I didn't even know how to ask.